# Request with patch verb

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have two microservices. The first one has the endpoint according the code below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/threshold/update/{id}/{valor}/{status}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Threshold updateThreshold(@PathVariable String id, @PathVariable String valor, @PathVariable Boolean status) {
    
    return thresholdQuery.updateThreshold(id,valor,status);
    
}
```

And the first one make a request to the second microservice, according the code below:

```
String url = new StringBuilder().append("http://localhost:8080/threshold/update/").append(id).append("/").append(valor).append("/").append(status).toString();
Threshold threshold = restTemplate.patchForObject(url, HttpMethod.PATCH,  Threshold.class);
```

The second microservice receive this request according the code below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/threshold/update/{id}/{valor}/{status}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
public Threshold updateThreshold(@PathVariable String id, @PathVariable String valor, @PathVariable Boolean status)  {
    
    return thresholdQuery.updateThreshold(id,valor,status);
}
```

the problem is that I got this erros below:

```
I/O error on PATCH request for \"http://localhost:8080/threshold/update/bola/dog/true\": Invalid HTTP method: PATCH; nested exception is java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH"
```

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1777#issuecomment-318293029 for a workaround.

Comment: According the code below:

restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.PATCH, entity, Void.class);

The problem is that I don´t need to send an entity to consumer the endpoint.

Isn´t there another method of restTemplate that I could use?

Comment: I changed to:

String aux = "";
HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(aux);
String url = new StringBuilder().append("http://localhost:8080/threshold/update/").append(id).append("/").append(valor).append("/").append(status).toString();
ResponseEntity<Threshold> threshold = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PATCH, requestEntity ,Threshold.class);
return threshold.getBody();

But still the same error.

Comment: How are you patching if you aren't sending an entity, using the path variables? What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: I´m using path variables. I´m using the newer version of Spring Boot.